# What is the time complexity of hash index in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, hash, query-optimization

I guess the creating hash index is O(n), while use it to access data also get O(n), so,it's better than b-tree index ?

Answer (score 2):

From the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/indexes-types.html):

> Note: Testing has shown PostgreSQL's hash indexes to perform no better
>   than B-tree indexes, and the index size and build time for hash
>   indexes is much worse. Furthermore, hash index operations are not
>   presently WAL-logged, so hash indexes might need to be rebuilt with
>   REINDEX after a database crash. For these reasons, hash index use is
>   presently **discouraged**.

Later versions of the manual don't mention the performance issues, only focus on problems with replication.

It looks like it doesn't make sense to use a hash index.

Comment: While in my application, there is no wal-logged or rebuilt problem. I care more about the complexity. So, could you suggest is my theoretical analysis correct ? @Frank Heikens

Comment: You have the same problem, you use the database and it's indexes. These hash indexes can't be trusted after a database crash (power outage or something like that). And why use some index that isn't any better then a btree index? You don't win anything but you do loose reliability. Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: well, I mainly focus on it's performance analysis as this is a research project, reliability is not the first priority for me ... and, I don't have need to consider crash ...

Comment: If you're worried about performance, stay away from hash indexes: "Testing has shown PostgreSQL's hash indexes to perform no better than B-tree indexes, and the index size and build time for hash indexes is much worse."

Comment: As you mentioned, that note is deleted in new version's document. I am wondered if the performance issue still exists or not?  @FrankHeikens